# Compare 2 python lists up to n-2 elements

Tags: python, python-3.5

Comparing two python lists upto n-2 elements:

```py
 list1 = [1,2,3,'a','b']
 list2 = [1,2,3,'c','d']

 list1 == list2 => True
```

Excluding the last 2 elements of the 2 lists they are the same.

I am able to do it by comparing each and every element of the 2 lists. But is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: `list1[:-2]==list2[:-2]` though this is not an efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return false after the first pair (a,b) where a != b

```
def compare(list1,list2):
    for a,b in zip(list1[:-2],list2[:-2]):
        if a != b : 
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `return all(a == b for a,b in zip(list1[:-2],list2[:-2])`

Comment: 'list1[:-2]==list2[:-2]' compares each item then reduces, no? In either case, you're still looking at O(n), so not that different. Verbosity for the purpose of communication.

Comment: @Rawing Does the list slicing comparison short circuit? they are at least difference since using `==` with lists items compares identities too, e.g. `[np.nan] == [np.nan]` vs. `np.nan == np.nan`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I can't say with absolute certainty if list comparison short circuits, but I'm pretty sure the python developers were smart enough to implement it efficiently...

Answer (score 4):

This way:

```
 list1 = [1,2,3,'a','b']
 list2 = [1,2,3,'c','d']

 list1[:-2] == list2[:-2] => True
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lists are very large and you want to avoid duplicating them with `list1[:-2]==list2[:-2]`, you can use a generator expression for a more memory-efficient solution:

```
all(a==b for a,b,_ in zip(list1, list2, range(len(list1)-2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just slice the lists directly...

`Python` has the syntax for slicing lists which looks like:

```
lst[start:stop:step]
```

a neat feature of this being that you can slice lists up to a position specified from the end using negative values. So if you have a list susch as:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

you can slice it with:

```
lst[:-3]
```

to get the values up to the third from the end:

```
[1,2,3]
```

so this can be used to compare your two lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,'a','b']
list2 = [1,2,3,'c','d']

list1[:-2] == list2[:-2] => True
```